# CRUD operation using angularJS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

I am creating an application of simple CRUD operation using **angularJS in Asp.net** **c#**.
I want to know, where I should keep code of CRUD operations?In .js file?
I also need a small demo of any one CRUD operation.
Please note that I am using **SQL database**.
Can anybody help me?

Comment: Extremely hard to find any angular introduction tutorial that doesn't include sample CRUD code

Answer (score 2):

You could starts learn AngularJs with:

- [The documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api)
- [PhoneCat Tutorial App](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial)
- [Build a Single Page Application (SPA) with ASP.NET Web API and Angular.js](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/build-a-single-page-application-(spa)-with-aspnet-web-api-and-angularjs)

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
    myapp.controller('mycontroller', function ($scope) {
        $scope.employees = [];
        $scope.AddDetails = function (employee)
        {

                $scope.employees.push(employee);
                $scope.employee = '';

        }
        $scope.DeleteDetails = function (employee)
        {

            $scope.employees.splice($scope.employees.indexOf(employee), 1)
        }
        $scope.EditDetails=function(employee)
        {
            $scope.employee = employee;

        }

        $scope.UpdateData = function () {
            $scope.employee = '';
        }

            //ClearModel();

        function ClearModel() {
            $scope.employees.Name = '';
            $scope.employees.Email = '';
            $scope.employees.Location = 0;
        }



    });
</script>
```

**and here is my HTML View.**

```
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="mycontroller">
    <div>
        Name
    </div>
    <div>
        <input id="txt_name" ng-model="employee.Name" name="name" />
    </div>
    <div>
        Email
    </div>
    <div>
        <input id="txt_email" ng-model="employee.Email" name="email" />
    </div>
    <div>
        Location
    </div>
    <div>
        <input id="txt_loc" ng-model="employee.Location" name="location" />
    </div>
    <div>

    <button type="button" id="Btn_save" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="AddDetails(employee)">Save</button>
        <button type="button" id="Btn_Update" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="UpdateData(employee)">Update</button>
    <div>
        <table class="table-bordered" width="600px">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>USER NAME</td>
                    <td>EMAIL ID</td>
                    <td>LOCATION</td>
                    <td>EDIT/DELETE</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
                <td>
                    {{employee.Name}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{employee.Email}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{employee.Location}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="EditDetails(employee);hideMe()">Edit</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="DeleteDetails(employee)">Delete</button>
                </td>

            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

</div>
```